# how to define an array of two types in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
class College {

    collegeTitle: String;
    collegeId:number
    course: String;    
    students: Student[];


    constructor( collegeTitle: String,collegeId:number , classroomname: String , students: Student[] ) {
     this.collegeTitle = collegeTitle ;
      this.collegeId = collegeId ;
        this.classroomname = classroomname;       
        this.students = students ;
    }
}
```

Earlier college had only one course .. so it worked fine..
now there are more courses and have to keep like array of course,students within the college.. what is the best way to achieve this?
I dont really need anything like map or other constructs since i am not retrieving them with key value ..I am just iterating and showing it in the UI
is it an array of interface or array of types? How will the code look like?

Comment: It's unclear what you're expecting to store, but I'd suggest something like `courses: { course: string, students: Student[] }[];`. Obviously you can name that interface if you like.

Comment: this is what i needed... thanks